# In Material UI when do we use Input vs. TextField for building a form?

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, textfield

Maybe this is just a basic question, but so far have not found any reasonable explanation. I am a beginner in React and using Material UI very recently. I am not very clear on when to use an Input vs. `Textfield` for building a form.

Looking at the documentation, it feels like `TextField` is a superset of what `Input` can do, but not sure. Material UI site uses examples for `TextField` and `Input` both, without stating the benefits of one over the other and any use cases.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

For most use cases, you should use `TextField` rather than the lower-level components that it delegates to (such as `Input`).

The relevant part of the documentation is [here](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#components).

Particularly this line:

> TextField is composed of smaller components ( FormControl, Input, FilledInput, InputLabel, OutlinedInput, and FormHelperText ) that you can leverage directly to significantly customize your form inputs.

The main reason to use these lower-level components is if you need to customize your form input in some way that isn't supported using `TextField`.

Answer (score 24):

This is a simplified definition of the [`TextField` component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/cc0e2ab63e8be9ec4d51a49bfde17ef28fc77b9c/packages/mui-material/src/TextField/TextField.js):

```
<FormControl {...other}>
  {label && (
    <InputLabel {...InputLabelProps}>
      {label}
    </InputLabel>
  )}

  {select ? (
    <Select {...SelectProps}>
      {children}
    </Select>
  ) : (
    <Input {...InputProps} />
  )}

  {helperText && (
    <FormHelperText {...FormHelperTextProps}>
      {helperText}
    </FormHelperText>
  )}
</FormControl>
```

As you can see, the `TextField` is more than an `Input`, it consists of:

- [`FormControl`](https://mui.com/api/form-control/#import): It's just a [context provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) that is used to pass the `TextField` state (focus, error, hover...) down to the children and make sure they stay consistent. You usually don't have to use this component directly.
- `InputLabel`: The label of the `TextField`, `Input` doesn't have one on its own, so if you want to add a label to your `Input`, use `TextField`.
- `FormHelperText`: The helper text placed below the `Input`, used to describe the `TextField` or display some error message in form validation.
- `Input`: The input itself. There are actually 3 input components in different variants: `Input`, `OutlinedInput` and `FilledInput` which can be set by the [`variant` prop](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#basic-textfield) in `TextField`. This is one more reason to use `TextField`, instead of finding and importing different input components, you can just set the variant prop and `TextField` will know what to render.
- `Select`: `TextField` can be either a `Select` or an `Input`. Set the [`select` prop](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#select) to change the input type to select.

So when to use `TextField`? In a form where you want to display an `Input` with a label and have a way to set the error message in a clean API, which is most of the time.

When to use `Input`? When you don't need all of the above except something to type in, or when you have a need for extreme customization and the [API](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#api) of `TextField` is not enough for you.

[image: Codesandbox Demo]