# Material UI Select - Change Select size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

whilst using the selects from Material UI, I'm struggling to get them working properly using a height and width with 'vh' and 'vw' appropriately and a text-size using 'vh'.

I end up having a proper size for the boxes, but the label text is not centered anymore due to apparently using a 'transform' to offset itself from the top left corner.

Anyway, here's what I have:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ujz2g

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormHelperText from "@material-ui/core/FormHelperText";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    width: "20vw"
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  select: {
    height: "10vh"
  },
  inputLabel: {
    fontSize: "4vh",
    alignSelf: "center"
  }
}));

export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLabelWidth(inputLabel.current.offsetWidth);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel
          className={classes.inputLabel}
          ref={inputLabel}
          id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
        >
          Age
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          className={classes.select}
          labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          labelWidth={labelWidth}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl variant="filled" className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-filled-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-filled"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
const { makeStyles, InputLabel, MenuItem, FormHelperText, FormControl, Select } = MaterialUI;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    width: "20vw"
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  select: {
    height: "10vh"
  },
  inputLabel: {
    fontSize: "4vh",
    alignSelf: "center"
  }
}));

function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLabelWidth(inputLabel.current.offsetWidth);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel
          className={classes.inputLabel}
          ref={inputLabel}
          id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
        >
          Age
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          className={classes.select}
          labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          labelWidth={labelWidth}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl variant="filled" className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-filled-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-filled"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<SimpleSelect />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

EDIT: the odd behavior is especially visible when zooming in and out - the label itself moves within the dropdown.

Answer (score 56):

Try using size="small" attribute on FormControl

```
<FormControl variant="filled" size="small">
    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-filled-label">Age</InputLabel>
    <Select
      labelId="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
      id="demo-simple-select-filled"
      value={age}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      <MenuItem value="">
        <em>None</em>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: One more thing that I usually keep banging against thoo:
The content of the `<MenuItem>...</MenuItem` can give material a shitfit even if its their own component. Example:` <MenuItem key={'1'} value={1}>
       1
    </MenuItem>
`
vs
`
    <MenuItem key={'1'} value={1}>
       <ListItemText primary={'1'}/>
    </MenuItem>
`
The first code will work with `size='small'` no problem, the second will break the height of the selector because ListItemText has a padding that cares not for the size

Comment: @DonKartacs Hey, am not sure about the exact/proper answer to this solution. But to get it to work, you can set the `style` attribute as `style={{margin:-2}}` on `<ListItemText>`. Hope this will help you, looking for an alternative way.

Answer (score 29):

Instead of declaring `FormControl`, `InputLabel` and `Select` manually and pass the `size` props to `FormControl`, you should create a [selectable `TextField`](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#select) and change the `TextField` `size` props.

It's the same as if you define a `Select` and `FormControl` but with [better integration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69416366/9449426). Here is a minimal example:

```js
<TextField select size='small' {...}>
  {names.map((name) => (
    <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
      {name}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 59196585/material-ui-select-select-size]

Comment: wow, never got the chance to see this. but works perfectly fine. thanks

Comment: OMG, you are awesome bro

Answer (score 4):

Try using style attribute on Select

```
<Select
  labelId="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
  id="demo-simple-select-filled"
  value={age}
  onChange={handleChange}
  style={{ height: 30 }}
>
  <MenuItem value="">
    <em>None</em>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a file `mystyle.css` and add the following entry in it. And finally import `mystyle.css` in your `demo.js`.

```
.MuiInputLabel-outlined {
  transform: translate(12px, 14px) scale(1) !important;
}

.MuiInputLabel-outlined.MuiInputLabel-shrink {
  transform: translate(12px, -6px) scale(0.75) !important;
}
```

**Working demo** : [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-uxjjh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thanks Himanshu! Unfortunately, the first label still is stuck at the top of the select element (compared to being in the middle as shown in the second one). But even if this would work, it would hard code the translation again, and this would work only on the resolution on which it was set upon, no?

Comment: @Bishonen_PL it will come back to its original position if you select "NONE" from dropdown. Do let me know what exactly do you want.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I could've stated the question better. The issue is exactly that the label for an not-yet-selected item is not centered. When an item is selected, it was already centered vertically in the codepen I posted, too.